# Azure Functions Node.js: write image to blob

Tags: javascript, node.js, blob, azure-blob-storage, azure-functions

I recently started using azure functions to convert a base64 string to an image and store this image in a blob.
But I didn´t find anything about how to write a specific file type to an blob, like I can do normally in Node with fs.writeFile().

Can someone tell me if it is even possible to do this with the normal "output" of Azure Functions?
Goal is that I can convert base64 string to an image and save it in a blob.

```
module.exports = function (context, input) {

    var image = input; 
    var bitmap = new Buffer(image, 'base64');

   //base64 string to test: "data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="

    function decodeBase64Image(dataString) {   
        var matches = dataString.match(/^data:([A-Za-z-+\/]+);base64,(.+)$/),
        response = {};

        if (matches.length !== 3) {
            return new Error('Invalid input string');   
        }

        response.type = matches[1];   
        response.data = new Buffer(matches[2], 'base64');

        return response; 
    }

    var imageBuffer = decodeBase64Image(input);

    //context.bindings.outputBlob = {'test2.jpg', imageBuffer.data};

    context.done(null, imageBuffer); 
};
```

My functions.json looks like this:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "manualTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "input"
    },
    {
      "type": "blob",
      "name": "outputBlob",
      "path": "logo/{rand-guid}",
      "connection": "npsmonitordev_STORAGE",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

In my test, I just set `outputBlob` equal to `imageBuffer.data` as below:

```
context.bindings.outputBlob = imageBuffer.data;
context.done();
```

and in my `function.json` I have this:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    //...
    {
      "type": "blob",
      "name": "outputBlob",
      "path": "outcontainer/{rand-guid}.png",
      "connection": "aaronchstorage_STORAGE",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

This will save buffer data as a bolb file to Azure storage.

[image]